# iphone Generating video from images

Tags: iphone, frame, ios4, movie

Is it possible to generate video from images in iphone OS 4.0? if so could anyone tell me how to do it ?

regards
John

Comment: have you got the solution ? I also face this problem .

Answer (score 0):

AVCaptureMovieFileOutput, but that doesn't let you specify your own images.